# Selenium -Select a future date from a date picker

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker, logic

I am trying to select a future date from a date picker but not able to understand how to go about doing this.

I need to select a date 14 days in advance but the date picker only shows one calendar month at a time. The picture has been uploaded to the following link.

[image]

What will be the logic of selecting a future date 14 days ahead?

=================================================================

## New Information

I looked more deeply in the element using firebug, the the datepicker is divided into row classes. Below is the export of the datepicker xml output:

```
    <tr class="w27"> <tr class="w28"> <td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell14" class="calcell wd0 d10 previous calcellleft">10</td> <td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell15" class="calcell wd1 d11 previous">11</td> <td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell16" class="calcell wd2 d12 previous">12</td> <td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell17" class="calcell wd3 d13 previous">13</td> <td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell18" class="calcell wd4 d14 previous">14</td> <td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell19" class="calcell wd5 d15 today selected selectable"> <a class="selector" href="#">15</a> </td> <td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell20" class="calcell wd6 d16 selectable calcellright"> </tr> <tr class="w29">

<td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell21" class="calcell wd0 d17 selectable calcellleft">
<td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell22" class="calcell wd1 d18 selectable">
<td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell23" class="calcell wd2 d19 selectable">
<td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell24" class="calcell wd3 d20 selectable">
<td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell25" class="calcell wd4 d21 selectable">
<td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell26" class="calcell wd5 d22 selectable">
<td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell27" class="calcell wd6 d23 selectable calcellright">
</tr>
<tr class="w30">
```

If you look at today's date, it has the following property:

```
<td id="startCalendarDiv_t_cell19" class="calcell wd5 d15 today selected selectable">
```

My thoughts were to find the element by class which has "today" in it and then identify the id, add 14 days to it and select it. Not sure how to get it done though.

Also, the 'findElement' is not working. The 'findElement' code which I have written is:

```
 //looking for the class
 driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("calcell wd5 d15 today selected selectable"));
```

Any clue what to do?

Comment: 1: Have you tried anything? 2: What is your outcome? 3: Show us your code. 4: Show us the HTML code behind this Calendar.

Comment: What language?Can you provide the link to the webpage or post the html code

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Shekhar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372554/642706) is correct, but uses old classes and works too hard.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 7 , 13 );
LocalDate twoWeeksLater = localDate.plusWeeks( 2 );
```

If your date picker widget has not yet been updated to work with `java.time` types, you may interrogate the `LocalDate` object for its parts.

```
int year = localDate.getYear();
int month = localDate.getMonthValue(); // The method `getMonth` returns an object from the `Month` enum rather than an integer.
int dayOfMonth = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic would be:

1. look for the highlighted date element
2. get the text value (in this case 13)
3. add 14 to that 13 = 27
4. look for the month and year (in this case July 2016)
5. get last date of July 2016 (in this case 31)
6. if no.3 above is beyond the last date of July 2016, reduce by that last date and add month by 1.
7. look for the element with text from no.6 and make sure you are at the same month as determined at no.6

-------------------Update after new info---------------------------

You cannot use By.ClassName, if class contains space char. Instead, to find the "today" in the class, use Xpath:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(@class,'today')]"));
```

Comment: The question is how to look for the highlighted item. Is there an option for look for highlighted date using c# or selenium?

Answer (score 0):

This is only Java code and nothing to do with Calendar Picker.

Just use this script in your code and use the 'newDay' string to enter in to the date box using SendKeys().

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    String todaysDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println(todaysDate);


    String month=todaysDate.substring(0,2);
    String day=todaysDate.substring(3,5);

    int monthValue=Integer.parseInt(month); 
    int dayValue=Integer.parseInt(day); 

    if(dayValue+14>31)
    {
        int temp= 31-dayValue;
        dayValue=14-temp;
        monthValue=monthValue+1;
    }
    else
    {
        dayValue=dayValue+14;
    }
    String newDay = monthValue+"/"+dayValue+"/"+"2016";
    System.out.println(newDay);
```

driver.findElement(by.xpath(DateBox)).sendKeys(newDay);

Comment: sendkeys won't work as the text box where the date goes is readonly